# How can I derive all the roots of a complex equation containing the square root of Sinh^2 using Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I have the following equation:

[image]

where m,n are arbitrary natural numbers and beta and k are positive nonzero real numbers.

How can I find all the roots of this equation using Mathematica?

Comment: Please post your code,not the picture.

Comment: I do not know how to do this? @cvgmt

Comment: Enclosed the code such as   ```  your code ```

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by copyting the code (in input form), pasting it, selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eq = {Exp[t (m + n)] (-b + k Sinh[t] - Sqrt[-b^2 + k^2 Sinh[t]^2]) == 
    0, {m, n} \[Element] PositiveIntegers, b > 0, k > 0};
Solve[eq, t]
```

[image]